# >> is changed to » using beramono

Tags: typewriter, beramono

I have the following piece of text in Latex: `\texttt{List<List<Integer>>}` and it was rendering properly. Then, I decided to use beramono as my typewriter font, and I have a problem: >> is now rendered as a » character. How should I fix it? In a listing environment, >> is shown correctly.

Comment: Have you tried writing `\verb+List<List<Integer>>+`? Just a guess. If you want to get answers without any guessing, you should provide a minimal working example of your problem.

Comment: Apart from the answers in that question, you can (if you use/are able to use `microtype` package) disable ligatures with `\DisableLigatures[<,>]{encoding=*,family=tt}`.

Comment: @Manuel I tried to disable them using your command, but didn't work. Any suggestions why?

Comment: @Ali The suggestion may came when we have a minimal compilable example of the code you are compiling. Without it, no one can know what's going on.

Comment: @Ali Although you should always post a minimal compilable example to show your problem (which helps everyone to answer your question), here it's a problem with me: I forgot a `*` after `tt`, you need to add it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `>>` is transformed into a ligature, which can be really beautiful for quotes. In this case you will have to split the ligature (`\texttt{<{}< {<}< <{<} <\/<}` or some `babel` shorthand...) or just use the `\verb` command which is meant for such purpose.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}

\begin{document}
\texttt{List<List<Integer>>} vs.\ \verb+List<List<Integer>>+
\end{document}
```

[image]